# generate sencha touch application

Tags: mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

i got this error after using sencha generate commande

```
C:\Users\usr\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342>sencha generate app  senchapp "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\senchaapps"
```

error after creating senchaapps directory :

```
[INF] generate-workspace:
[INF]
[INF] -after-generate-workspace:
[ERR] Unable to locate 'framework.dir' property from sencha.cfg
[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework directory
[ERR] Non-framework directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

actually, the sencha command should be run from the framework directory (touch-x.x.x folder) rather than the cmd directory. With your terminal, go inside this framework folder and then run this command:

```
$ sencha generate app nameOfYourApp ../Path/or/your/app
```

hope this will work.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i want just add that we have to use the relative path for me this path dose not work "C:\Users\nomade\Desktop\senchaapps" and we have to use the framework directory (touch-x.x.x folder) of the extracted folder of sencha-touch-x.x.x-commercial.zip

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem could be that you not set the SDK path:

```
 sencha -sdk ../bin/Sencha/touch-2.3.1/ generate app App .
```